# How to skip a iteration/loop in while-loop

Tags: java

Is there an elegant way to skip a iteration in while-loop ?

What I want to do is

```
  while(rs.next())
  {
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()){
      //then skip the iteration
     }
     else
     {
     //proceed
     }
  }
```

Comment: Why not just have an `if` with `f.isDirectory()`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

## `continue`

```
while(rs.next())
  {
    if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())
      continue;  //then skip the iteration
     
     else
     {
     //proceed
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 13):

While you could use a `continue`, why not just inverse the logic in your if?

```
while(rs.next())
{
    if(!f.exists() || f.isDirectory()){
    //proceed
    }
}
```

You don't even need an `else {continue;}` as it will continue anyway if the `if` conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: You will need an `||` instead of `&&` there.

Comment: Your inversing of the logic is not correct, you should have OR instead of AND

Comment: Oops, good spot guys, will amend that now.

Answer (score 9):

Try to add  `continue;` where you want to skip 1 iteration.

*Unlike the break keyword, continue does not terminate a loop. Rather, it skips to the next iteration of the loop, and stops executing any further statements in this iteration. This allows us to bypass the rest of the statements in the current sequence, without stopping the next iteration through the loop.*

http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/loopyjava/index.html

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for the `continue;` statement.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to skip the iteration, since the rest of it is in the `else` statement, it will only be executed if the condition is not true.

But if you really need to skip it, you can use the `continue;` statement.

Answer (score 4):

```
while (rs.next())
{
  if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory())
    continue;

  //proceed
}
```