# How to skip a single loop iteration in python?

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have the following code:

```
for i in list1:
    if i == 5:
        #skip the NEXT iteration (not the end of this one)
    else:
        #do something
```

How do I skip the iteration that comes after the iteration that throws the skip. For example, if `list1=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`, the loop will skip 6 and go straight to 7 because 5 triggered the skip
I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14856028/how-to-skip-a-iteration-loop-in-while-loop) question and several others, but they all deal with skipping the **current** iteration, while I want to skip the **next** iteration. The answers to those questions suggest `continue`, which as far as I can tell will stop the remainder of the current iteration and move on to the next one, which is not what I want. How can I skip a single iteration in a loop?

**Edit**: Using `next()` has been suggested, but this does not work for me. When I run the following code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
ai = iter(a)
for i in a:
    print i
    if i == 5:
        _ = next(ai)
```

I get

```
1
2
3
4
5
6 #this should not be here
7
8
```

Using `next()` is also the suggestion in this question: [Skip multiple iterations in loop python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22295901/skip-multiple-iterations-in-loop-python)

Comment: There's your bug: `for i in a:`. Should be `for i in ai:`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create an `iterator` from the list. With this, you can mutate the loop items while looping:

```
it = iter(list1)
for i in it:
    if i == 5:
        next(it) # Does nothing, skips next item
    else:
        #do something
```

In case you're planning to use the value at `i==5`, you should `do something` before the evaluating the condition:

```
it = iter(list1)
for i in it:
    #do something
    if i == 5:
        next(it) # Does nothing, skips next item
```

If you're doing this in a terminal, you should assign the next item to a variable as the terminal **may** force an autoprint on a dangling reference:

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> it = iter(list1)
>>> for i in it:
...    print(i)
...    if i == 5:
...       j = next(it) # here
...
1
2
3
4
5
7
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to actually skip the next iteration. When I add `print i` to the first line of the loop, it prints 1 though 7, when it should print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, skipping 6

Comment: I'm not using the terminal. I wrote and saved (and ran) a .py file

Comment: And it still does not work after you passed the output to a variable?

Comment: Yes, it still does not work

Comment: Please update your question with the changes you have made. or you could post the code in the comments if you choose not to, so we can have a look.

Answer (score 5):

Just set a flag:

```
>>> i
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> skip = False
>>> for q in i:
...    if skip:
...      skip = False
...      continue
...    if q == 5:
...       skip = True
...    print(q)
...
0
1
2
3
4
5
7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
runNext = True
for i in list1:
    if i == 5:
        runNext = False
    else:
        if runNext:
            #do something
        runNext = False
```

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. Is there a better method?